# Combinatorics Question with vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

How many 8-letter words contain exactly 5 vowels (a,e,i,o,u)? What if repeated letters were not allowed?

This question has two parts to be answered.

The first part is,"How many 8-letter words contain exactly $5$ vowels (a,e,i,o,u)?" so what I did did $8$ boxes, it can have all $5$ vowels and I am left with $3$ boxes left. So the answer is $(8C5)\cdot 5^5 \cdot 21^3$

now for the last part of the question,"What if repeated letters were not allowed?" so again I used the 8 boxes, and I can't use the same letters are vowels, so it's 5! because I can't repeat the letters. Each vowel is 5 boxes of the 8; $(8C5)$. Now I have 3 boxes left, this is where I am stuck, the answer has $(8C5)\cdot 5! \cdot (21P3)$. Why are they using permutation for the last three boxes?

Is it correctly done thus far?

Comment: You can not repeat the consonants either. So you have $21$ options to the first place of the non-vowels letters, $20$ for the second and $19$ for the thrid... which gives $21\times20\times19$ and is exactly $21P3$

Comment: Thank you @Gio that cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says no letters are repeated (which means none of the $8$ letters).

Once we find all combinations of $5$ places for vowels in the word, which is $\displaystyle {8 \choose 5}$, we only need to now permute vowels and consonants within themselves. Hence the answer.

**Another way** to look at it is that we choose $3$ consonants in $\displaystyle {21 \choose 3}$ ways and then permute all $8$ letters of the word, which is $8!$

So the answer is $\displaystyle {21 \choose 3} \cdot 8! \ $ which is same as the answer in your book.

Comment: I never thought about this way. 

you are excluded the repeats by doing the 8! right?

Comment: yes we know all $5$ vowels are anyway there. We now choose only consonants in ${21 \choose 3}$ ways. Now that we have all $8$ distinct letters, we permute them in $8!$ ways. I think it is simpler than first choosing $5$ places for vowels and then permuting them separately as the book does.

Comment: I hope it is clear why both lead to the same result.

Comment: it makes a lot of sense, thank you :) 

I will keep this method you showed me in mind.

Comment: you are welcome!